# Algolia for WooCommerce - Filter only through titles in the autocomplete

Tags: woocommerce, algolia

I'm trying to filter the autocomplete results in Algolia (in Woocommerce) by "post_title" only.

I have modified the template in child-theme/algolia/autocomplete.php :

```
attributesToSnippet: [
    'content:10'
],
```

by

```
attributesToSnippet: [
    'post_title'              
],
```

but it doesn't work, I have irrelevant results, as shown : https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1SKt.jpg

How can I achieve the desired result ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you would like Algolia only to return results by searching into the post titles.

The `attributesToSnippet` asks the engine to return a relevant snippet of a given size for a given attribute that matched the query. However in your case, this is not what you will want to change in order to only have the search operate on post titles.

Instead you should be changing the `searchableAttributes`.
You can do so by heading into your Algolia dashboard, going to the Indices tab and select your index. Then head to the `Ranking` tab and remove the attributes you don't want the engine to search on.

By only leaving the `post_title` in the searchable attributes, your autocomplete should only return results based on matches inside the `post_title`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this is working for instantsearch but not for autocomplete, this is why I was looking for the answer in autocomplete.php. Only "post_title" is in searchable attributes in my Ranking tab.

Comment: Could it be that you are using other indices in the autocomplete dropdown? You can check what is enabled on the Algolia Search -> Autocomplete screen.
You might want to adjust the searchableAttributes on the wp_posts_post index for example if that one is used.

Comment: I only have "Products" and "Product categories" enabled in the Autocomplete screen in my BO. In my Algolia dashboard, searchableAttributes are set to "post_title" only. I don't think I understand your last answer in order to browse through titles only for the autocompletion.